# Fastest way to split super long line into multiple lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a huge XML-File (about 1TB) that is written in one long line.
I want to extract some of its features and think that it is easier to do this, as soon as I have the long line split into new lines after each tag.

The file is built like that:

```
<textA textB textC> <textD textE textF> <textG textH textI>
```

I now started cracking the long line with this code:

```
eof = 0

while eof == 0:
    character = historyfile.read(1)

    if character != ">" and character != "":
        output.write(character)

    if character == ">":
        output.write('>' + '\n')

    if character == "":
        eof = 1
```

Unfortuantely this code will take about 12 days to process the whole file. 
I am now thinking whether there are much faster ways that can process the file in a similiar way with at least double time.

My first idea is to maybe just parse through the file and replace the closing tag like this:

```
for line in infile:

   line.replace('>', '>' + '\n')
```

Do you think this approach will be much faster? I would try it by myself, but I already have the first code running for 1 and a half days ;)

Comment: Why do you have such a huge XML file?!

Comment: How big is the document? How are you parsing the document? Maybe the inefficiencies are in your parser. Have you tried using lxml?

Comment: Why not use a streaming XML parser instead? The ElementTree API has an iterative parser (`iterparse()`) or you can use the [SAX incremental parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.reader.html) in the standard library directly.

Comment: your example isn't xml.

Comment: Why do you think this will take 12 days? You could thin up the algorithm a bit, but its still going to be faster than the hard drive. Open the files with large buffers (say, `16*1024*1024`) and let it rip. Add a counter that emits progress every meg to monitor performance. It'll dip a bit when the operating system starts flushing the output buffer to disk.

Comment: I always thought my file is an XML-file: The first charakters look like that:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><osm version="0.6" generator="OpenStreetMap HistoryDump.java" timestamp="2013-02-05T17:01:47Z" copyright="OpenStreetMap and contributors" attribution="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" license="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/"><bound box="-90,-180,90,180" origin="http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6"/><changeset id="1" created_at="2005-04-09T19:54:13Z" ....> <...> and so on.

Comment: Okay, that is an xml file. Your exmample wasn't. `<textA textB textC>` is very different than `<textA textB="one thing" textC="another thing">`.

Comment: OK, sorry! I'm quite green in all these things.
So you think an XML-Parser would be much more reasonable and faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you would try to just read the file line by line, which would be just one line of 1TB you would get a `str` variable of the same length. I do not know the implementation details, but I would guess, a `MemoryError` is raised long before reading finished.

Comment: I did not experience any memory errors as the code is writing character by character to my simple textfile. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: Considering your question, if your approach with the for loop would be faster.

Comment: Ah obviously! Thank you for the hint!